# Exception logger. No entiendo como puedo probar este código

Tags: python, excepciones

Soy nuevo y en una tarea tengo que construir un exception logger.  Me dan una estructura y me piden elevar tres tipos de error.  Para mi *args y **kwargs son los parámetros pero debo probar la salida.  Es decir que debo llamar una función para el código y debo crearla?.  No es clara la instrucción .  Aquí esta el código pero no se como probar para tener resultado en **inner**

```
def exception_logger(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print(type(e).__name__)
            pass
        except ArithmeticError as e:
            print(type(e).__name__)
            pass
        except AssertionError as e:
            print(type(e).__name__)
            pass
    return inner
```

Se supone que este método, se aplica a una función y si esta se ejecuta con esos 3 tipos de error descritos (Arithmetic, division cero o Assertion error) debe imprimir el nombre del error.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Que pena con uds.. para mi tampoco es claro.. se supone que este método, se aplica a una función y si esta se ejecuta con esos 3 tipos de error descritos (Arithmetic, division cero o Assertion error) debe imprimir el nombre del error

Comment: Tal vez sea de ayuda que pongas el enunciado de tu problema junto a lo que has intentado. Si tienes dudas puedes leer [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Lo que has escrito, es decir una función que recibe otra como parámetro y que devuelve otra función más como resultado, es lo que en general se llama un "decorador".

La idea del funcionamiento es la siguiente. Supón que tenemos una función como esta:

```
def dividir(a, b):
   return a/b
```

Cuando la ejecutas por ejemplo con `dividir(5, 2)` te retornará 2.5. En cambio si la ejecutas con `dividir(5, 0)` elevará una excepción de `ZeroDivisionError`.

Lo que se pretende es que la función `exception_logger()` que has escrito sea usada de algún modo "alrededor" de la función `dividir()` para que cuando esa excepción se produzca, en vez de romper todo, simplemente se muestre por pantalla un mensaje. Lo que tú preguntas cómo sería ese "de algún modo".

### Respuesta complicada (bajo nivel)

Si te fijas en tu función `exception_logger()`, verás que espera como parámetro una función. Podríamos pasarle `dividir`, así: `exception_logger(dividir)`. ¿Qué ocurriría entonces?

La función `exception_logger()` crea en su interior otra función llamada `inner`, y eso es lo que te retorna. Vamos entonces a recoger eso que ha retornado en otra variable:

```
funcion_retornada = exception_logger(dividir)
```

Hasta aquí la función `dividir` no ha llegado a ejecutarse. Sólo se ha pasado como parámetro. La función `inner` tampoco ha llegado a ejecutarse, sólo se ha devuelto como resultado y ahora mismo tenemos una variable llamada `funcion_retornada` que apunta en realidad a `inner`, por lo que si en este momento ejecutaras `funcion_retornada()`, se estaría ejecutando `inner()`

Pero observa que desde dentro de `inner` hay una línea que hace `funcion(*args, **kwargs)`, es decir, que llama a la función que se le hubiera pasado a `exception_logger()` (que en este momento era `dividir` y se le pasaría a ella los mismos parámetros que en ese momento se le estuvieran pasando a `inner()` (o sea, a `funcion_retornada()`)

Por tanto se puede realizar la siguiente invocación:

```
funcion_retornada(5, 0)
```

Eso llamará a `inner(5, 0)`, la cual a su vez llamará a `dividir(5, 0)`, que elevará una excepción. `inner` capturará esa excepción y la mostrará por pantalla. El resultado por tanto de ejecutar lo anterior es que se imprime el mensaje

```
ZeroDivisionError
```

### Mejorando la experiencia del programador

Lo anterior ha servido para explicar cómo usar el decorador, pero es inconveniente que ahora para llamar a `dividir()` tengamos en cambio que llamar a `funcion_retornada()`.

Pero ¿por qué no cambiar la variable `funcion_retornada` por otra que se llame `dividir` (igual que la función original). Eso haría que el símbolo que apuntaba a la función original quede apuntando a la "nueva versión" que es `inner`.

Es decir, reescribiento otra vez todo el ejemplo (salvo tu función `exception_logger()` que se queda como estaba) haríamos:

```
def dividir(a, b):
  return a/b

dividir = exception_logger(dividir)
```

Y ahora ya puedes hacer `dividir(5, 0)` y obtener el mensaje de error.

### Respuesta más simple (alto nivel)

Todo lo que acabamos de hacer puede hacerse con una sintaxis mucho más amigable en Python.

Se trata de la siguiente:

```
@exception_logger
def dividir(a, b):
  return a/b
```

Esto hace exactamente lo mismo que lo que vimos en el apartado anterior. El símbolo `@` indica que debe ejecutarse lo que hay tras él (`exception_logger`) pasándole como parámetro la función que se defina justo debajo (`dividir`) y que el resultado de esa ejecución debe asignarse de nuevo al símbolo `dividir`.

Es decir, la sintaxis:

```
@A
def B()
  ...
```

Básicamente hace:

```
def B()
  ...
B = A(B)
```

## Pruebas

Hemos probado que `dividir(5, 0)` genera correctamente el mensaje de excepción. Pero si prueba `dividir(5, 2)` verás que no obtienes el resultado esperado (2.5) sino que no obtienes nada. ¿Por qué?

Debido a que hemos decorado `dividir`, al ejecutar `dividir(5, 2)` ya no se ejecuta la función original, sino en su lugar `inner(5,2)`. Por tanto el valor resultante será el que retorne la función `inner` y si te fijas en su código resulta que ¡no retorna nada! Se limita a llamar internamente a `funcion()` pero no devuelve el resultado que ésta haya producido.

Por tanto una implementación mejor sería:

```
def exception_logger(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)  # <<---- Observa el return añadido
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print(type(e).__name__)
            pass
        except ArithmeticError as e:
            print(type(e).__name__)
            pass
        except AssertionError as e:
            print(type(e).__name__)
            pass
    return inner
```

Ahora si, al hacer `dividir(5, 2)` (una vez decorada la función) verás que sí recibes la respuesta 2.5, mientras que `dividir(5, 0)` sigue produciendo el mensaje de la excepción.

En cuanto a cómo probar las otras excepciones es algo más complejo, pues son excepciones que python no eleva de forma natural. Nuestro sencillo ejemplo `dividir` no sirve, y hay que crear otro ejemplo más artificial y forzado, que pueda generar diferentes tipos de excepción según sus parámetros.

Por ejemplo:

```
@exception_logger
def dividir_artificial(a, b, solo_positivos=False):
  assert isinstance(solo_positivos, bool) # Debe ser un booleano
  if solo_positivos and (a <0 or b < 0):
    raise ArithmeticError("No se admiten negativos")
  else:
    return a/b
```

Veamos unas cuantas ejecuciones de prueba:

```
>>> dividir_artificial(5, 2)
2.5

>>> dividir_artificial(5, 0)
ZeroDivisionError

>>> dividir_artificial(5, -1)
-5.0

>>> dividir_artificial(5, -1, solo_positivos=True)
ArithmeticError

>>> dividir_artificial(5, -1, solo_positivos=1)
AssertionError
```